# Export conversations from Botpress

Tags: botpress

How can I easily export all the messages from my conversations with the chatbot? When I try to export the logs from Botpress the text file is always empty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sql lite database for all logs or if you are using postgress you can check the tables.